# regular expression to detect consecutive numbers - not working for non-English input

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match, multibyte

Hi All I have this code that checks for 5 or more consecutive numbers :

```
if (preg_match("/\d{5}/", $input, $matches) > 0)
return true;
```

It works fine for input that is English, but it's tripping up when the input string contains Arabic/multibyte characters - it returns true sometimes even if there aren't numbers in the input text.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Any chance you could paste your erroneous `$input`? I'm very interested in seeing this error.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be using PHP.

Do this:

```
if (preg_match("/\d{5}/u", $input, $matches) > 0)
return true;
```

Note the 'u' modifier at the end of expression. It tells preg_* to use unicode mode for matching.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set yourself up properly when you want to deal with UTF-8.

You can recompile *php* with the PCRE UTF-8 flag enabled.

Or, you can add the sequence `(*UTC8)` to the start of your regex. For example:

`/(*UTF8)[[:alnum:]]/`, input `é`, output `TRUE`

`/[[:alnum:]]/`, input `é`, output `FALSE`.

Check out http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt, which contains lots of information about UTF-8 support in the PCRE library.

Comment: Disclaimer: This was pure research; I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Hi there, I already use UTF8 normally even for english - the problem si not with UTF8 it's more with multibyte characters, i've updated the description

Comment: @SherifBuzz: As I understand it, that's what the PCRE flag enables support for. Multibyte is somewhat inherent in UTF-8. [Single-character] ASCII is assumed otherwise. May I ask how you know that your English strings are multibyte?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal my english strings aren't multibyte - the Arabic ons are - I remember seeing a solution somewhere that involves using iconv for a similar problem, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @SherifBuzz Thanks for your very helpful bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Even in UTF-8 mode, predefined character classes like `\d` and `[[:digit:]]` only match ASCII characters.  To match potentially non-ASCII digits you have to use the equivalent Unicode property, `\p{Nd}`:

```
$s = "12345\xD9\xA1\xD9\xA2\xD9\xA3\xD9\xA4\xD9\xA5";
preg_match_all('~\p{Nd}{5}~u', $s, $matches);
```

[See it in action on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/EGzcF)

If you need to match specific characters or ranges, you can either use the `\x{HHHH}` escape sequence with the appropriate code points:

```
preg_match_all('~[\x{0661}-\x{0665}]{5}~u', $s, $matches);
```

...or use the `\xHH` form to input their UTF-8 encoded byte sequences:

```
preg_match_all("~[\xD9\xA1-\xD9\xA5]{5}~u", $s, $matches);
```

Notice that I switched to double-quotes for this last example. The `\p{}` and `\x{}` forms were passed through to be processed by the regex compiler, but this time we want the *PHP* compiler to expand the escape sequences.  That doesn't happen in single-quoted strings.